# Diode and capacitor circuit after diode rectifier. Why?

Tags: bridge-rectifier

I came across this design. Basically, it's a rectified power supply that is used to power a big coil. The coil is connected beetween B1 and gnd.

[image]

My concern is about the diode D2 in series with C27. What is their purpose?

Comment: No idea but parasitic coupling from flyback is negative won't be suppressed by D2 blocking that.

Comment: Is there anything not shown that's connected to the cathode of D2?  I've seen that in power supplies where you need a power rail for some control electronics that's guaranteed to be at a higher voltage than the low point of the ripple on the "main" DC bus (the one labeled "325V_DC" in this schematic).  But I don't see the point of making it and not using it unless it was left in from an older revision of the circuit.

Comment: no, nothing connected on D2.

Comment: Why does the word "relais" (relay) appear in the schematic. The devil will be in the detail and you need to dig deeper. Look at earlier revisions of that circuit and convince yourself that the diode and cap are not some throwback like the appendix in a human.

Comment: Eagle eye! "relais" word should have been removed from this schematic.  In a previous version, drain of Q2 was to connected to 325v_DC or to a 25v source. Source selection was acheived by a relay.